# Convert For-Loop into Java stream

Tags: java, for-loop, java-stream

I'm new to Java 8 Streams and I'm currently trying to convert a for loop into a java 8 stream. Could I get some help?

```
for (Subscription sub : sellerSubscriptions) {
    if (orders.get(Product).test(sub)) {
        orderableSubscriptions.add(sub.getId());
    }
}
```

---

```
sellerSubscriptions = List.

orders = Map<String,Predicate<Subscription>>

orderableSubscriptions = Set<String>
```

Comment: how about you try, and ask what you're doing wrong once you tried?

Comment: @Stultuske, or just post the question like he did. Chances are that someone enjoys the challenge and provides a quick answer? :-)

Comment: what does `orders.get(Product)` even signify? what is `Product`?

Comment: @Naman Product is a string and orders.get(Product) basically looks for a key that is the same as Product and runs a predicate(value in the map).

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a `Stream` of `Subscriptions` via the `Collection#stream()` method
2. Use of the `Stream#filter()` method to "simulate" the `if` statement, by filtering out all subscription that don't pass the given predicate.
3. By using the `Stream#map()` method you convert your stream of subscriptions, to a stream of ids
4. Finally by using the `Stream#collect()` you can collect the stream into anything you'd like. E.g. a `Set`

Your code could look like this:

```
Set<String> ids = sellerSubscriptions.stream() // create a Stream<Subscription>
    .filter(orders.get(Product)::test)         // filter out everthing that doesn't match
    .map(Subscription::getId)                  // only use the ids from now on
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());              // create a new Set from the elements
```

Some notes:

- `Subscription::getId` (a method reference) is functionally equal to the lambda `sub -> sub.getId()`
- `orders.get(Product)::test` (also a method reference) retrieves the predicate only once. As it seems to be the same predicate for all your subscriptions

  - Though it is **not** equal to `sub -> orders.get(Product).test(sub)` as that would invoke `orders.get(Product)` for every element

Comment: from the question *`orderableSubscriptions = Set<String>`*

Comment: @Apollocy You're welcome, I suggest going a bit through the java doc of the `Stream` interface to get a better feeling of all the different methods you can use. The ones I've shown are just some of the basics.