# Java 8: assigning a value from a stream to a variable?

Tags: java, loops, java-8, java-stream

I just started to learn streams in java8. I am trying to convert a basic for each loop into a stream that does the exact same thing. I have checked around here and found this:
[Convert For-Loop into Java stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56274366/convert-for-loop-into-java-stream). The issue with this is that the example collects the results at the end and I don't think I need to collect anything but to assign the value which is not explained.

the loop which I want to convert is this. As you can see I want to assign the value to the vanTire.

```
VanTire vanTire = null;

        for (Object tire : tireList) {
            if (tire instanceof VanTire) {
                vanTire = (VanTire) tire;
            }
        }
```

What I have so far with streams is this. How do I assign the value to the vanTire variable since filtering and casting is already done?

```
tireList.stream()
    .filter(VanTire.class::isInstance)
    .map(VanTire.class::cast)
```

Comment: In general, you don't assign values from within the stream to a variable; you extract a result from the stream (like the last `VanTire` instance).

Comment: Do you want the very last element from the loop only? Since that is what your original loop is doing. If not, you should `break;` upon the first match. It is completely unecessary to loop the full list if you already found your match.

Comment: hei Zabuzard, i managed to do make it work, thanks and greetings to you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting the correct items, you need to use `.findFirst` or `.findAny` to get an element, along with `orElse` to provide a default value

```
VanTire vanTire = (VanTire) tireList.stream().filter(VanTire.class::isInstance)
                                    .findAny().orElse(null);
```

- `.elseGet` and `.elseThrow` in [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) documentation
- `.findFirst` or `.findAny` in[`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) documentation

Comment: You meant .orElseGet and .,orElseThrow here in the **Optional** documentation?

Comment: filter(tire -> tire instanceof VanTire) can be filter(vanTire.class::isInstance)

Comment: I suggest being consistent. Either use `.filter(VanTire.class::isInstance) .map(VanTire.class::cast)` or use `.filter(tire -> tire instanceof VanTire).map(tire-> (VanTire)tire)`. But note that the mapping step is obsolete here. You can apply the typecast when assigning: `VanTire vanTire = (VanTire)tireList.stream().filter(tire -> tire instanceof VanTire).findAny().orElse(null);`

Answer (score 2):

In general, [`Stream`s should be stateless](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html). This is due to the fact that the elements in `Stream`s might be processed out of order. Thus, I would suggest a solution that does not assing the value from within the `Stream`, but rather yield a result from the stream that is assignable to the desired type:

```
VanTire vanTire = tireList.stream()
    .filter(VanTire.class::isInstance)
    .findAny()
    .map(VanTire.class::cast)
    .orElse(null);
```

I used [`.orElse(null)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElse(T)) since this maps to the semantics of the sample code provided wrt. the behaviour when `tireList` is empty. Depending on the business case, however, continuing computation with an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html) or calling [`orElseThrow(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#orElseThrow()) might be a better option.

Comment: When you want the same semantics as the provided sample code, you need to replace `findAny()` with `reduce((a,b) -> b)`, as the loop keeps the last element when there are multiple occurrences.

Comment: @Holger true. I reworded my answer in this regard.